# how to run javascript object from string without using eval()

Tags: javascript, eval

i have a json object that has item type and id, i need to create new object

```
var data = { 
            "items":[
                    {"type":"generator","id":"item_1","x":200,"y":200},
                    {"type":"battery","id":"item_2","x":50,"y":300},
                    {"type":"generator","id":"item_3","x":200,"y":280},
                    {"type":"battery","id":"item_4","x":100,"y":400}
                ]
        };
```

and i need to run for each item in items

```
jQuery.each(data.items, function(index,value) {
    eval("var " + value.id + " = new " + value.type + "(" + (index + 1) + ");");
    eval(value.id + ".id = '" + value.id + "';");
    eval(value.id + ".draw(" + value.x + "," + value.y + ");")
});
```

this is not a good practice, but what else can i do?

i need then to have the control on the items

something like

```
    item_1.moveto(300,700);
```

but i always get item_1 is undefind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a factory method which allows to generate concrete types out of an abstract data structure:

```
var createItem = (function () {
    var types = {};

    function createItem(index, data) {
        data = data || {};

        var ctor = types[data.type], item;

        if (!ctor) throw new Error("'" + data.type + "' is not a registered item type.");

        item = new ctor(index);

        item.id = data.id;

        return item;
    }

    createItem.registerType = function (type, ctor) {
        types[type] = ctor;
    };

    return createItem;

})();
```

Then register item types to the factory:

```
function Generator(index) {/*...*/}

createItem.registerType('generator', Generator);
```

And finally create an object map to lookup your items by id (you could use a specialized object like ItemsMap instead of a plain object), loop through your items and add them to the map.

```
var itemsMap = {};

data.items.forEach(function (itemData, i) {
    var item = itemsMap[itemData.id] = createItem(i + 1, itemData);

    //you can also draw them at this point
    item.draw(itemData.x, itemData.y);
});
```

You can now lookup objects by id like:

```
var item1 = itemsMap['item_1'];
```

Comment: This is a very good pattern. Is it not better removing the registerType function and moving the type functions (ie. Generator,etc) directly into the anonymous function? (If they are not used outside)

Comment: Also if you use "this[itemData.id] = createItem(i+1, itemData)" inside the forEach, you can remove itemsMap object and directly call "item_1".

Comment: @plbsam Using the module pattern can be considered yes, but using `this` within `forEach` would pollute the global namespace so it's not an option. You do not want to create a global variable for every item.

Answer (score 2):

```
var objects = {};

objects[value.id] = new window[value.type](index + 1);
```

Comment: What's going on here: a global variable like `generator` is really a property of the global object, which in a browser is `window`.  So plain `generator` means the same thing as `window.generator`.  The dot syntax is just a shortcut for the bracket syntax that you can use when the field name fits the pattern for an identifier (variable name), so `window.generator` is exactly the same as `window['generator']`.  That means that if `value.type` contains the string `'generator'`, `window[value.type]` is automatically the same function as the literal `generator`.  No `eval` required.

Comment: how then i call to the object? i try item_1

Comment: What if the functions are not defined at window but inside another function? Shouldn't it be this[value.type] ? @SLaks

Comment: @eyalb An object in JS is just like a map. You can lookup your objects by `id` using `objects['item_1']`.

Comment: @plbsam It's probably better to use a factory like I describe below. You can then register new types independently of where they live and it free's the client from knowing these details.

Comment: You should consider not only using a dictionary for `object`, but also for the `constructors` - instead of using the global `window`.